# Spring Boot Security: Logout action returns 404

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, logout

I configured my app with two Authentication Managers: A Basic Authentication for API routes and a Form Login for Web routes. Here is my [Security Configuration](https://gist.github.com/efraimcf/8499667ff876c5394ed88581dbdd83f7). Authentication goes fine in both cases, but when I tried to logout, the application returns a 404 page.

```
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.980 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@250f659c |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/css/**' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/js/**' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/images/**' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/**/favicon.ico' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/error' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/auth**' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.983 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy /logout has an empty filter list |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.985 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/logout] |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.996 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping Matching patterns for request [/logout] are [/**] |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.997 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping URI Template variables for request [/logout] are {} |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:47.999 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping Mapping [/logout] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4c6bba7d]]] and 1 interceptor |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.000 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Last-Modified value for [/logout] is: -1 |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.004 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.004 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Successfully completed request |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.006 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.006 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@250f659c |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.012 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error] |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.015 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'httpErrorHandler' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.015 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1 |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.182 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*]) |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.203 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.205 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@19fd8351] based on requested media type 'text/html' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.205 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@19fd8351] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.322 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor' |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.695 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.u.c.s.ResourceBundleThemeSource Theme created: name 'theme', basename [theme] |#]
[#|DEBUG| date=2016-05-26 time=18:12:48.702 thread=http-nio-8080-exec-1 class=o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Successfully completed request |#]
```

Anyone has an idea to solve my problema?

Comment: Your spring logic expects a template as a destination for your logout and doesn't find it. That's the reason why the 404 being thrown.